# Why does new data to an async pipe not cause data to rerender?

Tags: angular, reactjs, behaviorsubject

I've been reading a lot of background on Angular/ReactJS and trying to get a good understanding of the lifecycle hooks and how it all plays together, but something that still confuses me is the following scenario.

Say you have a someService and in that service you define a BehaviorSubject called someBehaviorSubject. It is defined inside someService as:

```
public someBehaviorSubject= new BehaviorSubject<someInterface[]>([]);
```

That behavior subject is then subscribed to `someAPIcall(argument: string): void`. someService.someAPIcall is defined as:

```
someAPIcall(argument: string): void {
  this.http.get<someInterface[]>(argument).subscribe(this.someBehaviorSubject);
}
```

someInterface is defined as:

```
interface someInterface {
  data: string
}
```

Say there is a parent component called someParent and a child called someChild. someParent has two buttons which call:

```
someService.someAPIcall("A");
```

and

```
someService.someAPIcall("B");
```

respectively. someChild has the following in a template:

```
<div*ngFor="let data of someService.someBehaviorSubject | async">
  {{data}}
</div>
```

In my observations, when you click button A or button B in someParent, the data correctly renders either dataset A or B. However, if you click the other button after the first set of data has rendered it **does not** rerender the data with the new dataset. I expected that it would with the async pipe being directly subscribed to the BehaviorSubject. I don't understand why the data isn't redrawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to update the `BehaviorSubject` value you need to use the `next()` function which will push the new value into the `BehaviorSubject`.

Example:

```
someAPIcall(argument: string): void {
  this.http.get<someInterface[]>(argument).subscribe(data => 
{
   this.someBehaviorSubject.next(data); 
});}
```

For more information about RxJS subjects, consider checking the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).

Comment: This was mostly correct! As mentioned in the documentation here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject BehaviorSubject is natively both an observer and observable. I didn't have to cast it with "asObservable". The piece I was missing was calling next. For some reason I thought that was implied so you didn't have to call it explicitly. If you update the answer I'll accept this one! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Thanks, I am glad that it worked... i updated my answer.